# Direct AJAX printing

Tags: ajax, printing

I am looking for a specific printer or a technology (interface, standard, protocol) that exists on some printers, which makes it possible to implement direct printing from a web browser with AJAX.

That means that the printer must:

- Network interface
- Implement a web server (fairly common)
- Have support for HTTP delivery of a document for printing, for example PDF file
- SSL with custom certificate
- CORS support for ajax

I am sure that many printers have the actual abilities to do this, but have not been able to find a specific documented implementation. Not even contacting some of the major printer vendors helped in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://developers.hp.com/printos/device-api. Or https://github.com/hpinc/printos-device-api-example-java, https://developers.hp.com/printos/doc/box-documentation#direct_file_submission for practical examples.

Even better using https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/overview, so that you can cut specific implementation off, but benefit using any cloud ready printers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Google Cloud (and PrintOS) have two drawbacks. Each print operation takes quite some time, which is a problem in our case. And we need to open up for internet access. That's why I am looking for a way to submit such files directly to the printer (if at all possible).